# 'make' is not recognized is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: makefile, path, windows-7, gnu-make

I'm try to execute 'make clean' within a directory with several .c and .h files as described under the windows 7 portion of this tutorial (https://github.com/grbl/grbl/wiki/Compiling-Grbl). However, when I do so I keep getting the error "'make' is not recognized is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file."

I added the path to the make.exe file to PATH in my user variables. In fact, whenever I type path in the command line "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" shows up. Also, whenever I navigate to to "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" in the command prompt and enter 'make' I get the resulting output: "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop."

Does anyone have any idea of what I need to change to fix this issue? I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: Do you get the same error when trying to execute other binaries in the same folder? If so then clearly it's a PATH issue.

Comment: What would be an example of an another binary to execute?

Comment: Look in the binary directory and try to execute one from a directory where invoking make gives you the error, presumably you have GCC in there? Side note: GnuWin32 doesn't look like it's been updated in a very long time.

Comment: I got it working. I had spaces between my paths. Once I removed those and restarted, everything worked!

Comment: You might want to consider deleting your question as it isn't very useful for future visitors.